React component not re-rendering on set state
Considering the following react component:
import React, {forwardRef, useState, useEffect} from 'react'
import type {SxProp} from '@primer/react'
import {UnderlinePanels} from '@primer/react/experimental'

export type TabsProps = SxProp & {}
export interface TabsHandle {}

const Tabs = forwardRef<TabsHandle, TabsProps>(({}, _ref) => {
  const [tab, setTab] = useState<1 | 2>(1)

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('Tab', tab)
  }, [tab])

  return (
    <UnderlinePanels>
      <UnderlinePanels.Tab aria-selected={tab === 1}>Tab 1</UnderlinePanels.Tab>
      <UnderlinePanels.Panel>
        Panel 1<button onClick={() => setTab(2)}>Switch</button>
      </UnderlinePanels.Panel>
      <UnderlinePanels.Tab aria-selected={tab === 2}>Tab 2</UnderlinePanels.Tab>
      <UnderlinePanels.Panel>Panel 2 </UnderlinePanels.Panel>
    </UnderlinePanels>
  )
})

Clicking the button does log "2" in the console, but the component does not re-render, and still displays tab 1. How comes?

Thanks @DBS for the feedback. If I useState(2) from the beginning, I confirm the tab 2 is displayed. This is documented here: https://primer.style/components/underline-panels/react/draft#underlinepanelstab.

I will respond to myself that, in the above scenario, I'd probably use the UnderlineNav component rather than the UnderlinePanels component of the primer library. It is then possible to achieve the desired effect., while keeping a very similar (if not identical) UI.
